# Application not verified. Google OAuth2

Tags: google-oauth

Please help me!

I look everywhere but still not understanding.

I have domain domain1.com and I want to get access to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" scopes for my project - quickstart-111111.

I already add my domain and verify it through DNS TXT record with the help of "https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home  ". Also I add my domain there - https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/domainverification?project=quickstart-111111. Also I add "https://domain1.com:4455" to accessible JavaScript resources, and "https://domain1.com:4455/GoogleAcc/Register" to allowed redirect URI.

Question is why Google say that "Application not verified". Where I can verify it?

I try to register GSuite account (https://gsuite.google.com/signup/basic/accountandrecaptcha) but it want to register my corporative email as "something@domain.com" but I already have it and do not want to migrate my email to Google!

My registration link looks like - https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&prompt=consent&redirect_uri=https://domain1.com:4455/GoogleAcc/Register&client_id=11111-hash.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&response_type=code&state=/profile&nonce=1589225765743

Comment: I guess I found it.

I need to pick "access request window" and there choose some info.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865

Of course I found simple answer after read a half of Google Search.